# ECLIPSE: can't download new software, stays stuck in 'pending...'

Tags: eclipse

using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

I know there are similar questions (out-dated by the way) but none can solve my problem
i go to HELP -> Install New Software -> Work With

and select

Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

and it keeps saying 'Pending...'

Any ideas?? i'd be VERY grateful

:D

EDIT: by the way, nothing on the error log

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to "Preferences"->"Install/Update"->"Available Software Sites" and uncheck all except "Indigo". Then try again. I think eclipse gets updates from all sites before it gets through "Pending..."-stage.

Then re-check items until you find the one that causes it to jam.

Comment: You can also reload the lists from the Preferences page directly. At least it shows a progress bar, which seems better than the "Pending..." status at the "Install New Software"  window.

Comment: @Lycha I am using Eclipse Mars version. I tried your solution, but its not working. Can you pls help?

Answer (score 4):

Check if there is proxy server configuration that prevent the direct access. you can define it in the preferences.see more details [here](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I use proxy setting, and I follow the answer provided by oshai, and it works. But just one small modification for [the post](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/): the SOCKETS setting should be clear and empty as suggested by [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/110146/)

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Sockets setting need to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I don't know if you had the same problem as me. But mine was stuck at Updating software and I wanted to update my ADT plugin for ecliplse. I started fiddler and unchecked everything except ADT plugin to track which website is blocking the updates.

Guess what things just started working as if Eclipse got scared of fiddler :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue and I solved it by closing and re-opening Eclipse.