# Eclipse: install new software pending

Tags: eclipse

Just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), Build id: 20160218-0600).

When I tried to install new software, Eclipse just "Pending" there without any progression. No error messages, either.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852708/eclipse-cantt-download-new-software-stays-stuck-in-pending), but it didn't work.

Eclipse Mars 2 worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. So, what was the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822242/eclipse-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-16-04)  and it worked.

Simply add

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

in the `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: I ended up installing NEON, everything runs fine.

Comment: Additional to this change. In the "Available Software Sites" preferences I had to uncheck "Mars". I guess its support is discontinued. After that I could work with "--All avilable sites--" without a problem. Also note that I had to remove the "--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417" line and change it for the "--launche.GTK_version 2"

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue can make your software list empty, 
it can happen when you encounter an error while installing a new software.

To solve it you've to delete some rows in one of your metadata file:

- go in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml`
- delete these rows :

  `<item value="0" key="AvailableVersionColumnWidth"/>`

  `<item value="0" key="AvailableNameColumnWidth"/>`

*note : I prefer share my research here instead of launching a new thread.*